# Proof of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{t^h-1}{h}=\ln t$ please

Tags: limits, logarithms

I should know this, but I don't. Please help me understand why $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{t^h-1}{h}=\ln t$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on an elementary analysis.  Here we use only a well-known pair of inequalities and the squeeze theorem.

Note that $t^h=e^{h\log(t)}$.  Now use the inequalities

$$1+x\le e^x \le \frac1{1-x}$$

for $x<1$.

Finish by using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I'm a fan of the different approach. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The accepted answer seems to use a circular argument.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it was the first answer that I understood immediately.

Comment: That's fine.  But how does one find the derivative of $x^h$ with respect to $h$?

Comment: We treat $x$ as a constant, then do the following: $$D_h x^h=D_h e^{h\ln x}=e^{h\ln x}D_h h\ln x=x^h \ln x$$

Comment: @clathratus I understand.  So, if one starts with that characterization of the exponential function, then the answer to your question seems trivial, does it not?

Comment: What do you mean by characterization?

Comment: See [This](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function)

Comment: Ohhh. That's what you mean. I don't think that the definition of the exponential function that we use really matters other than the fact that we use the property $$e^{\ln x}=x$$ $$\therefore a^x=(e^{\ln a})^x=e^{x\ln a}$$

Comment: One starts with a definition and then develops properties.  Using just the property you wrote, how do you evaluate the derivative?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Oh I just figured out that your answer was the one I needed all along. Thanks!

Comment: @clathratus Pleased to hear.  And you're welcome.  It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ t^h - t^0}{h-0} = \frac{d}{d h} t^h \bigg|_{h \to 0 } = t^h \ln t \bigg|_{h=0} = \ln t$$

Comment: Ooh it's nice and simple! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

we have the problem:
$$L=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}$$
firstly notice that:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left[x^h-1\right]=\lim_{h\to 0}\left[h\right]=0$$
so this satisfies the conditions for L'Hopitals rule which states:
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f'(y)}{g'(y)}$$
and so:
$$L=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^h\ln(x)}{1}=x^0\ln(x)=\ln(x)$$
and so there is the proof

Comment: Beautiful! This one clears things up a bit.

Comment: This seems a bit circular.  How does one show that the derivative of $x^h$ is $\log(x)x^h$?

Comment: @MarkViola $$D_h x^h=D_h e^{h\ln x}=e^{h\ln x}\ln x=x^h\ln x$$

Comment: $x^h=e^{h\ln(x)}$ and then take $\frac{d}{dh}$ also the OP is not asking for a proof of the derivative, only an evaluation of this limit

Comment: @henrylee And how does one evaluate the derivative of $e^x$?  What characterization are you applying?

Comment: @MarkViola $$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$$

Comment: That is one characterization.

Comment: @MarkViola do you mean notation? If that's what you mean, then $$D_h f(h)=\frac{d}{dh}f(h)$$ It's just a shorthand notation

Comment: No.  How does one define the exponential function.  There are many such characterizations which one can show are equivalent.

Comment: I don’t understand what you are arguing about. Nothing used in my working is hard to understand and is all pretty standard and known by OP too

Comment: If $f(x) =t^x$ then note that $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{t^h-1}{h}$ and if you know via some means that $f'(x) =t^x\log t$ then you already know the limit in question to be $\log t$. It is a bit roundabout to use L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Hi Paramanand!  It's always nice to see you're still here.  This was my point.  The answer presupposes knowledge of the derivative of $f(x)=t^x$.  But if this is already known, the limit is trivial.